# anchor is not working after callback append in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

t I have been trying to resolve this issue for two days, and I'm getting crazy, plea a little help.
I'm trying to append a new div (insert html code), within an anchor, it seems ok, but the link does not work. I'm trying to use a class='delete', to call another jquery function to deleted the new div element. The idea is a shopping cart, I add a producto, and after added, I want to delete, but it's not working. Here is my code:

```
$("#dialog-form").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 320,
    width: 320,
    modal: true,
    show: 'slide',
    buttons: {
        "Agregar Tour": function () {
            var bValid = true;
            allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");

            bValid = bValid && checkLength(adl, "Adultos", 1, 5);
            bValid = bValid && checkLength(chls, "Niños", 0, 5);
            bValid = bValid && checkLength(fecha, "Fecha", 1, 16);

            var id = $(this).val("id");
            var string = 'tourid=' + tourid;
            //var tourid = '<?php echo $moneda ?>';
            //alert(tourid);
            if (bValid) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "add_item.php",
                    data: "tourid=" + tourid + "&adl=" + adl.val() + "&chl=" + chls.val() + "&fecha=" + fecha + "",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: "GET",
                    cache: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        var regis = data[0];
                        var titulo = data[6];
                        var desc = data[7];
                        var total = data[12];
                        var foto = data[15];
                        var items = data[21];
                        var ruta = "images/hoteles/" + foto + "";


                        $("#containerx").append("<div id='containerx' class='koko' ><b><font color='#3399CC'>" + titulo + "</font></b><br>" + desc + "<br>" + "<b><font color='#ff0099'>Sub-total </font></b><image src='images/arrow.gif'> $" + total + " MXP " + "<a href='#' id=" + regis + " class='delele'>" + "<image src='images/delete.gif'></a></div><div style='clear:both;'></div>");
                        $("#containerx.koko").fadeTo(1000, 0.7);




                        $("#dialog-message").dialog({
                            modal: true,
                            show: 'slide',
                            buttons: {
                                Ok: function () {
                                    $(this).dialog("close");
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        $("#items").html("<div id='items'>[" + items + "]</div>");

                        $('#load').fadeOut();

                    }
                });
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        },
        Cancel: function () {
            $(this).dialog("close");
        }
    },
    close: function () {
        allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
    }
});

$(".add-item").button().click(function () {
    tourid = $(this).attr("id");
    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
});
```

Comment: did you mean `<img src=` instead of `<image src=`?

Comment: one more: did you mean `class='delete'` and not `class='delele'`?

Comment: yes, sorry it was a typo error !

Comment: please show some more research efforts before posting questions. see the [FAQ entry on this](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Answer (score 0):

On this "delete" event etc you need to use "live" jquery live http://api.jquery.com/live/ or attach the events again after you add content.

Simply once content is rendered all events are attached, if you are dynamically adding new content you need to attach events again if they are not "live" events.

jquery "Live" event will try to attach to dynamically added content also :). Read the doc i added and you will know all.

Comment: Live is deprecated, as of jQuery 1.7 you should be using http://api.jquery.com/on ... and live doesn't work they way you describe.  It doesn't "attach to dynamically added content" - you attach the handler at a higher level in the DOM that isn't being replaced and it uses event bubbling to apply the handler even when a new element is the source of the event  by applying the selector to the event target in the delegated handler.

Comment: You mean, instead of using $("#containerx").append( , I need to use $("#containerx").live( ?, I tried this but it does not work.

Comment: please take a look at this working example: http://traveldepot.com.mx/shopping_cart.php?action2=viewk , sorry is in spanish, but if you ADD (with "seleccionar") items, you will see what I'm talking about. The delete function (trash can) does not work, until you press "MIS VACACIONES" on the top menu, any help?